# How to change http request headers in Mozilla firefox and i.e. 7?

Tags: web-services, http-headers

I need to send some HTTP headers (such as  Client freshness - max-stale, min_fresh no_store, etc) in request, and clinets are Mozilla 5.0 and i.e. 8.

Can I do this without using any tool such as fiddler etc?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you cannot without some external tools.
Firefox has a useful extension, called Tamper Data:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966/

which allows you to inspect and change headers and post parameters.

Comment: Do you know a tool that can change the headers in IE8? I need to simulate another IE-OS-combination.

Comment: To answer myself: I did it with apaches mod_header in a htaccess like this: `RequestHeader set User-Agent "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)"`